# Using particle system to array objects on vertices

Tags: particles

I would like to use the hair particle system to make a random 'fence' so at every vertex I add a particle which comes from a group. It works but it does not add a particle to every vertex. (The number or particles is the as the number of vertexes of the base object)

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you upload the Blend? I would expect the settings you have to work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to uncheck the "Random" box.
[image: 1 particle for 1 vertice]

(Note: this answer was posted before the question showed that "Random" was unchecked already.)